# Dependency Is not satisfiable : libstdc++6 (>=4.8.0)

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, google-chrome, dependencies

When I try to install Chrome through the Ubuntu Software Center, I get the message

> Dependency Is not satisfiable : libstdc++6 (>=4.8.0)

How can I fix this?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Yes, I am using Ubuntu version 12.04

Answer (score 4):

[The version of `libstdc++6` in Ubuntu 12.04 is 4.6.3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libstdc%2B%2B6&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). In order to get version at least 4.8.0, you will need to upgrade to at least 14.04, which has version 4.8.4.

Since `libstdc++6` is an essential system package, trying to install the 14.04 version manually, or to upgrade it by some other "hacky" method, will probably result in a broken system.